# Mongoose .populate() is not populating due to MissingSchemaError

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to populate a `users` array with user info that's using an Object ID reference in Mongoose.

Here is my `user.js` model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var User = mongoose.Schema({
    conversations: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Conversations'
        }
    ],
    messages: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Messages'
        }
    ]
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', User);

module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback) {
    var query = {username: username};
    User.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback) {
    User.findById(id, callback);
}
```

And my `conversation.js` model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Conversation = mongoose.Schema({
    created_at: Date,
    created_by_user_id: String,
    sent_to_user_id: String,
    messages: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Messages'
        }
    ],
    users: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }
    ]

});

var Conversation = module.exports = mongoose.model('Conversations', Conversation);
```

I'm using them in my `users.js` route like so:

```
var User = require('../models/user')
var Conversation = require('../models/conversation')

router.get('/member', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {
  Conversation.find({ users: req.user._id }).populate('users').exec((err, conversations) => {
    // Code
  })
})
```

`.populate('users')` is not executing.  I get this error: `MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "User".`  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model name you are exporting in user.js is `Users` and you are trying to reference it with `User` in conversation.js that's why it's giving you error. Change `User` to `Users` and it should work

Comment: Dude, I love you.  I have been banging my head over this thing for far too long.  Thanks a million!